# Switching control to a Modal window (not an alert) using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, modal-dialog, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application that launches the Save Window (which is Modal) when I click on the Save Button. This window takes uptil 10 seconds to load completely (I can counter this with a wait).
I need to carry out some actions in this window, before I complete the save.

The problem I face is
- The moment the modal window is launched, there is no way I can use a driver.SwitchTo() or driver.Manage().GetAllWindowHandles() etc. I confirmed this with the following lines of Code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toolbar']/a[1]")).click();
// After the above line is executed, the Popup gets launched

Set<String> sWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println("Popup"); 
System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandles().size()); // This always prints "1"
```

The 3 lines above are not executed at all (or at least not for a long time) until I explicitly close the Popup Window.

How do I work on some control that exists within the Save Window (Modal), when there is no way I can find the Window's handler?

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

doesn't work, because immediately after the modal window is opened (makes sense to GetWindowHandles only after it is launched), the subsequent lines aren't executed at all.
I'm caught in a deadlock. Please help me out.

Comment: You might be looking at this wrong - Modal dialogs on web pages are usually not separate windows; they are mostly implemented as div overlays on the page. Share the HTML of your page, and that of the modal dialog also please.

Comment: If the dialog is launched using `showModalDialog`, you should have a look at [Issue 284](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=284). Start reading from the bottom up for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows handles is not working on an Application.
Java robot class function can be used.

```
      Robot robot = new Robot();   
//Doing a mouse over for the X and Y coordinates of button/link which opens modal window
robot.mouseMove(210,350);  
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);  
robot.delay(100);  
//Clicking tab til the cursor is on specific position (textbox/button)
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);  
robot.delay(100);  
//Doing a mouse over for the X and Y coordinates of button/link
robot.mouseMove(300,150);  
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);  
robot.delay(100);
```

For more information refer the below link.
http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke

Comment: I'm not 100% certain on how to identify the co-ordinates. I believe you are asking me to hover over the Buttons in the modal window directly and click, without even collecting the WindowHandle.

Comment: You can get the approximate X,Y coordinates in the layout tab of firebug window in the right corner. Make sure you maximize the browser  , once the browser is opened.

Comment: Inspect the element of which you want to know the XY coordinates, get it from layout tab and test it, if the cursor is not on the exact position you want, you can assume and modify the coordinates from the place where cursor is positioned. I usually do that in one of my projects in which window handles dont work.

Comment: The Robot suggestion didn't work unfortunately. The MouseMove operation, similar to the GetWindowHandlers(), fails to work as long as the Modal Window is alive.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes find the windowhandles can take a while to update with the correct value even though the popup is visible. To counter this I use a loop which breaks when the windowhandles reaches the expected size.